# Warning - Targets a different processor than the application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compiler-warnings

My .NET 3.5 WPF application has started showing a bunch (14) of the the following warning (with different dlls):

```
Referenced assembly 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.TeamFoundation
\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll' 
targets a different processor than the application.
```

I am running on a 32 bit machine.  The only project in my solution is set to compile to "Any CPU".  (A rebuild all does not fix it.)

I would rather not recreate my solution.  Does anyone else know another fix/workaround for this issue?

NOTE: I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and Windows XP 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen that one specifically but the download samples for C++ by default build for Itanium - did you install the wrong version of those libs?

Comment: I should have specified, but I am using C# and WPF.  (Not C++)  An my code is not a sample download but something I made.

Comment: Yes but did you download/select the correct TeamFoundation SDK - did you somehow get the Itanium one?